# SciPy Leastsq implementation issue

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares

I am using the code below to implement a least sqaures fit of my model vs some experimental data.
The program just keeps running and it seems there is something wrong with my implementation but I am not able to figure it out. Print statements in the two functions(simulateFunc and fit) indicate that these are called a few times(9 to be precise), but after that there is no response.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my implementation? The program runs fine without the leastsq function being used, I am able to get residuals returned to me by calling the fit function with some parameters.

Sample data points : ( I have a total of 100 in my file) 
0.944444444,2.838888889,5.711111111,2.962962963,0.481481481
0.822222222,2.672222222,5.855555556,3.259259259,0.351851852

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Simulate egg-laying in hermaphrodites

import math
import csv
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

f = open('dataPointsCSV.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f : 
    ####### My Model #######
    def simulateFunc(parms) : 
        oocytes = 0 
        sperm = 300
        eggs = []
        total_t = 0
        delta_t = 0.1
        bin_size = 4

        k_o = parms[0]
        k_c = parms[1]
        k_f = parms[2]
        k_s = parms[3]

        while(sperm > 1) : 
            oocytes += delta_t*(k_o-k_c*oocytes)
            new_eggs = delta_t*min(k_f*oocytes,k_s*sperm)
            sperm -= new_eggs
            oocytes -= new_eggs
            index = int(total_t/bin_size)

            if(len(eggs)<=index) :
                eggs.append(new_eggs)
            else :
                eggs[index] += new_eggs

            total_t += delta_t

        for i in range(0,len(eggs)) :
            eggs[i] = eggs[i]/bin_size

        return eggs
    ######## Returns the residuals #########
    def fit(para) :
        newEggs = []
        modelEggs = simulateFunc(para)
        exp = np.array(row)
        expEggs = exp.astype(np.float)

        ########## Get the required points for calculating the residuals from the model data ############
        for i in range(0,len(modelEggs)):           
            if(i == 2 or i == 4 or i == 9 or i == 15 or i == 22):
                newEggs.append(modelEggs[i])

        newEggs = np.array(newEggs)
        res = expEggs - newEggs
        return res

    ######## Parameter Initializations ##########
    parameters = [6,-.02,.0266,.0625]

    x, cov, infodict, mesg, ier = leastsq(fit,parameters, full_output = True, epsfcn = 1.0e-2)
    print x
```

Comment: Is it always the same row in the input that causes the program to stop?

Comment: it doesn't stop, just keeps running and produces no output. It stays in the first row itself.

Comment: I added epsfcn = 1.0e-4/1.0e-5/1.0e-3 as an additional parameter to the leastsq function and it produces some outputs before getting stuck again, also, it gives me some warnings like : RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  oocytes += delta_t*(k_o-k_c*oocytes)
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  oocytes -= new_eggs

Comment: You'll need to fix part of your code shown: indentation is incorrect at points, and the `fit` function is chopped in two, which makes it looks like it doesn't return.

Comment: Perhaps you can copy-paste all your data (100 lines doesn't seem overly many) into [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/); then turn your code into 1 self-contained program that we can try.

Comment: Your `fit` function is incorrect: what is `row`?

Comment: row corresponds to rows from my input file. I will upload the file to pastebin. I will also upload my python script there.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Zya3ZH0A --> Data points

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qhRfcFDX -->Python code

Comment: Why do you have your function defintions inside a for loop? Pass `row` as an extra parameter to `fit` and you can take the function definitions outside the loop, afaict.

Comment: gave it a try, but that didn't change anything, same output as before.